# Give dynamic height to bottom Tabbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, tabbar, tabwidget

Now, I have make it with Fixed height. Here is my code.

I want to give this height as dynamic according to screen resolutions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
{
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 130;
    if (i == 0)
    {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my question

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            // Log.e("Selcted : ", ""+i);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = getHeight(getApplicationContext());
            if (i == 0)
            {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }
            else
            {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
```

Get height from below method and you will get perfect height for your Tabbar.

```
 public int getHeight(Context context)
    {
     Resources resources = context.getResources();
 int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0)
 {
return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
 return 0;
}
```